# UIApplication.shared.backgroundTimeRemaining always less than two seconds

Tags: ios, swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    application.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
    return true
}



 func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "smat.Tracker")
        switch UIApplication.shared.applicationState {
        case .active:
            print("App is active.")
        case .background:
            print("App is in background.")
            print("Background time remaining = \(UIApplication.shared.backgroundTimeRemaining) seconds")
        case .inactive:
            break
        }
        print(UIApplication.shared.applicationState.rawValue)
        print(configuration.allowsCellularAccess)
        print(configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource)

        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [

            "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
            "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "referer": "https://frys.com/",
            "host":"frys.com",
            "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
        ]
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = headers
        let base_url: String = "https://frys.com/search?search_type=regular&sqxts=1&cat=&query_string=" + "vivomove" + "&nearbyStoreName=false"
        let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
        print("came here")
        if(Trackers.urls.count > 0 ){
            print(Trackers.urls.count)
        }

        Alamofire.request(base_url , headers: headers).responseString { response in
            //print(response.result.value)
            do {
                print("response12 ")
                guard let doc = try! response.result.value else{
                    completionHandler(.noData)
                    throw NSError(domain: "ERROR", code: 42, userInfo: ["BKGROUND":"err"])
                }
                completionHandler(.newData)
                //self.endBackgroundTask()
            }
            catch {
                print("error")
            }
        }


    }
```

I have the above code in AppDelegate.swift. I read in several documents / tutorials that the minimum time required to finish a background task is 30 seconds or more. Why do I always get the above to be less than 2 seconds?

sample output below from console:

App is in background.
Background time remaining = 1.79769313486232e+308 seconds
0.0
1.79769313486232e+308
UIApplicationState

Comment: I have no idea what these triggers mean, how do we check those and how do I specify which one to use?

Comment: Are you running under Xcode - if so you get infinite background time - look closely at that number it is 1.797 x 10^308 - a very big number indeed

Comment: My bad! that was so stupid of me. Yes, I'm using xcode.

Comment: @Paulw11 what do you mean by "you get infinite background time" when running under Xcode?

Comment: When you run an app under the Xcode debugger iOS will never terminate it for using too much background time. When you run an app normally background time quotas are applied and iOS will terminate your app if you exceed those quotas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you're running it under the XCode debugger.

While using a debugger, you receive `bacgroundRemainginTime = 1.79769313486232e+308`, which is a huge number (1.79 * 10 ^ 308). It's the largest positive representable number in double-precision floating point format.